# Script to retrieve computer objects in specific AND display their respective OU's

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting

I have an OU with many sub-OUs, each with an OU for computers.  The highest level OU to start is 'Departments' with many sub-OU's.

I need a script to retrieve all computers and list them in a table with their respective OU displayed.

The result of the script might look something like this:

Computer Name        ---       OU

***Computer01***    ----      ***Fabrikam.com/Departments/Finance/Computers***

....or it might even look like it's corresponding AD 'Object':

***Fabrikam.com/Departments/Finance/Computers/Computer01***

Although I much prefer the first one.

This is the script I've tried, but it throws out tons of errors when I run it:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"

objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000

objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://OU=Departments,dc=fabrikam,dc=com' WHERE " & _
        "objectCategory='organizationalUnit'"  

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Set objOU = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value)
    Wscript.Echo objOU.distinguishedName

    objOU.Filter = Array("Computer")

    For Each objItem in objOU
        Wscript.Echo "  " & objItem.CN
    Next

    Wscript.Echo
    Wscript.Echo
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

How can I retrieve all computers in an OU and have them listed in a table with their respective OU's?  Seems simple, but I can't find a working script anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you considering this powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is vbScript, but this is much easier to accomplish in powershell, and you did post in the powershell forum.

This will provide what you're looking for. Sometimes I prefer to use canonicalname over DistinguishedName.

This will require RSAT to be installed, or run from a domain controller.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
get-adcomputer -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -SearchBase "OU=starthere,DC=yourdom,DC=com" | select DistinguishedName
get-adcomputer -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -SearchBase "OU=starthere,DC=yourdom,DC=com" -prop canonicalname | select canonicalname
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add the VBScript tag too.  I was hoping to get any type of script (PS, VBS, etc.) to get what I need.  Thanks, Craig620.

Comment: If this does what you need, you can mark it as answered